# logcat while using external storage

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-external-storage

My app needs to access external storage, but phone doesn't let to do that if it is connected to PC by cable. But I can't get logcat if it is not connected by cable. Any ideas how could i get to see logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access adb/logcat through a wireless connection. You will need root access.
Also be mindful to not leave the service supplying access running all the time as it is a potential security risk.

Here is an app that I've used in the past but there are many to choose from:
(or the manual method as linked in [Hans Kratz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24288734/1590950))

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wave18.adbwireless

Comment: I downloaded the app, connected it to my wifi. I try to execute "adb connect "and given ip"" in cmd.exe but it doesnt work: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command....... Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If `adb` is not recognised then you either need to add the location inside your `.../AndroidSDK/platform-tools` directory that contains the `abd` program to your System/User path variable (google for OS specific instructions) or navigate to that location manually and run it from there.

Comment: finally managed to connect. Didn't see your edit and kept searching for adb in tools. Thanks.

Comment: @user3134759, glad you got it working. I'll leave you [this handy tool](https://github.com/marshall/logcat-color) that you might find useful. I'm a fan. If you use it it's definitely worth setting up a profile or two.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- [Connect using adb over TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)
- Use a logcat app such as [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat). Please note that this only works on Android before Jelly Bean or rooted devices.